# Display Many-To-One fields in Symfony2 forms?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having two entity files one as Activite.php and another as Mesurage.php. 
Now i want to display an Activite form with 3 fields typeActivite, emplacement and mesurage. the mesurage will be a selection that will fetch data from mesurage table. here is the code that i wrote inside Activite.php to create a many_to_one field for mesurage_id

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Entity\Mesurage")
 */
private $mesurage;
```

Below is my Form generation Code :

```
class ActiviteType extends AbstractType {
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
         $builder
             ->add('typeActivite'),
             ->add('emplacement'),
             ->add('mesurage', 'entity', array('class' => 'ISO14001Bundle:Mesurage'));
     }
}
```

here is my form code :

```
<div class="well">
<form method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <br/>  <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
var $container3 = $('div#gestionenvironnementale_iso14001bundle_activitetype_activiteMesurage');
var $lienAjout3 = $('<a href="#" id="ajout_mesurage" class="btn">Ajouter un mesurage</a>');
$container3.append($lienAjout3);
$lienAjout3.click(function(h) {
        ajouterMesurage($container3);
        h.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
var index3 = $container3.find(':input').length;
    if (index3 == 0) {
        ajouterMesuragePolluant($container3);
    } else {
        $container3.children('div').each(function() {
            ajouterLienSuppression3($(this));
        });
    }
function ajouterMesurage($container3) {
        var $prototype3 = $($container3.attr('data-prototype').replace(/__name__label__/g, 'Mesurage n°' + (index3+1))
                .replace(/__name__/g, index3));
        ajouterLienSuppression3($prototype3);
        $container3.append($prototype3);
        index3++;
    }
function ajouterLienSuppression3($prototype3) {
        $lienSuppression3 = $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer</a>');
        $prototype3.append($lienSuppression3);
        $lienSuppression3.click(function(h) {
            $prototype3.remove();
            h.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    }
 });
```

the code works very well but I dont want to display the list of Mesurage, I want to display the form of Mesurage to add a new !!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display a form even for `mesurage`, you have to take a look at [embed form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

So, basically, you have to create a `FormType` for `mesurage` (call it `MesurageFormType`) and modify your `ActiviteType` as follows

```
class ActiviteType extends AbstractType {
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
         $builder
             ->add('typeActivite'),
             ->add('emplacement'),
             ->add('mesurage', 'collection', array(
                 'type'      => new MesurageFormType(),
                 'allow_add' => true,));
   }
}
```

This should be fine but if you want to render in a different way your form you should use [prototype and jquery](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype)

Comment: thank you for your reply but I have already done this solution without success
the type collection is designed for one to many relationship not for many to one !!

Comment: @YassineEch-Charafi: ? I see from your mappings that has a many to one fashion (and, however, is not that importa as you could hack around i think)

Comment: i dont understand what do you mean !! but in JQuey code i have nothing to show !!

Comment: @YassineEch-Charafi: your mapping (Activite.php) says that fashion is ManyToOne and not OneToMany :)

Comment: I do not know please see the jquery code above to see if there is an error :)

Comment: @YassineEch-Charafi: this shouldn't be a treasure hunt. why don't this works for you, in few simple words? :D

Comment: i have no idea may be the error is in controller or in the jquery code !!

Comment: actually I have two entity Activite and Mesurage that are many to many relationship with attributes !! through entity is ActivitePolluant !!